# how can I replace all zeros in a list with hundred in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
listzero = [0,0,0,0,0]

for q in listzero:
    if (q==0):

        print("zero is present ")
        listzero.remove(0)
        listzero.append(100)


    else:
        print("non zero list")

print(listzero)
```

Output:

```
zero is present 
zero is present 
zero is present 
non zero list
non zero list
[0, 0, 100, 100, 100]
```

My Expected output is

```
zero is present 
zero is present 
zero is present
zero is present 
zero is present 
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

Comment: `[x or 100 for x in [0,0,100,100,100]]`

Comment: In general, it's bad practice to modify a list while you iterate over it.

Answer (score 5):

```
listzero.remove(0)
```

removes the first 0 element, but

```
listzero.append(100)
```

adds `100` at the end of the list (plus the fact that you shouldn't change the list while iterating, except for item assignment, since it confuses the loop internal index)

Other answers show how to change values within a loop, but
you can also use a list comprehension instead. It doesn't replace the list, but creates another one, here with an idiomatic expression (since we test the `0` value) to set to `100` when `0` appears (thanks to the `or` operator):

```
listzero = [0,0,100,200,300]
listzero = [x or 100 for x in listzero]
```

(I've set different values to demonstrate the code, and assigning it back to the original list name to "overwrite" it)

result:

```
[100, 100, 100, 200, 300]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
listzero = [0,0,0,0,0]
final_list = [i if i != 0 else 100 for i in listzero]
```

Output:

```
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre probably missing a � :P

Comment: Ajax has fixed the issue. note that `i if i else 100` is shorter (or `i or 100` like in my answer)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was attempting to make a joke about [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2017/11/07/apple-confirms-ios-11-1-autocorrect-bug-and-suggests-this-workaround/#d36f1cd6b7ac) whole situation...

Comment: I'll check that later, cannot seem to follow the link (maybe my dumb firewall at work)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ios 11.whatever started autocorrecting lowercase "i" to a broken unicode character which was printing � everywhere...

Comment: oooh applies really well here. Spot on :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for n in range(len(listzero)):
    if listzero[n] == 0:
        listzero[n] = 100
```

This will edit your current list in place in case you don't want to create another one.

A more pythonic variant using `enumerate`:

```
for n,v in enumerate(listzero):
    if not v:
        listzero[n] = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
newlist = [100 if x == 0 else x for x in listzero]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too:

```
listzero = [0,0,0,0,0]
listzero = list(map(lambda i: 100 if i==0 else i, listzero))
print(listzero)
```

The result is:

```
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do it in place (which means directly substitute 0 with 100):

```
listzero = [0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(len(listzero)):
    if (listzero[i] == 0):
        listzero[i] = 100
        print("zero is present ")
    else:
        print("non zero list")
print(listzero)
```

More "Pythonic" way to do it using list comprehension:

```
listzero = [0,0,0,0,0]

listzero = [100 for x in listzero if x == 0 else x] # we overwrite listzero here
```